# Return a series of dates in excel based on a manual Month/Year entry

Tags: excel

I am looking to create a cell in which I can enter a MM/YY entry and it will return inputs in different cells.

Ex.
Entry
    A1= 10/2016

Excel would prepopulate

```
A2= 9/2015
A3= 10/2015
A4= 11/2015

B2= 6/2016
B3= 7/2016
B4= 8/2016
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried literally anything?

Answer (score 1):

Format the cells A1:B4 as `m/yyyy`

Then use these two similar formulas:

In A2:

```
=EDATE($A$1,ROW(1:1)-2)
```

In B2

```
=EDATE($A$1,ROW(1:1)-5)
```

and copy/drag the formulas down to the forth row.

[image]